# How to specify minInstancesPerNode parameter for Random Forest?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

It doesn't look like it's possible to specify `minInstancesPerNode` for Random Forest in pyspark. I cannot see it in the scala code, but it's mentioned in the [spark R library](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/R/spark.randomForest.html) and in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-decision-tree.html#stopping-criteria). It says:

> minInstancesPerNode: For a node to be split further, each of its
>   children must receive at least this number of training instances. This
>   is commonly used with RandomForest since those are often trained
>   deeper than individual trees.

Is it possible to use this parameter for Random Forest in spark (pyspark specificaly)?

Comment: I see, it does have it. I've checked this one `from pyspark.mllib.tree import RandomForest`. It was mentioned in spark code examples and in the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html. It didn't realize that there are two different wrappers for random forest. I guess it solves my problem. Can you post your response as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier), `minInstancesPerNode` is an input paramter for `pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier`.

You are likely looking at a different implementation of RandomForest, perhaps the `mllib` one.